# C# Best way to wrap calls to an interface?

Tags: c#, oop, mutex, wrapper

I am working with legacy code, and converting single-instance implementations into multiple instance.

The basic example below illustrates what I am doing -

1. Creating a object that wraps each call of an interface with a
   disposable mutex (to give a nice using{...} block), and
2. passing an instance of an object that uses the interface into an
   instance of the wrapper object.

code here:

```
    // An Interface
public interface IImplementation
{
    void DoSomething();

    double MeasureSomething();
}

// An implementation
public class Implementation : IImplementation
{
    private int iparam;
    private string sparam;

    public Implementation(string sparam, int iparam)
    {
        this.sparam = sparam;
        this.iparam = iparam;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //actually do something here
    }

    public double MeasureSomething()
    {
        double value = 0.0;
        //actually measure something here
        return value;
    }
}

// a disposable safety wrap object
public class SafetyWrap : IDisposable
{
    public SafetyWrap(string resource)
    {
        mutex = new Mutex(false, resource);
        try
        {
            if (mutex.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite) == false)
                throw new TimeoutException("Timed out trying to acquire lock");
        }
        catch (AbandonedMutexException)
        {
            // Log "Caught abandoned mutex"
        }
    }

    private Mutex mutex;

    #region IDisposable Members

    private bool disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                mutex.Close();
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~SafetyWrap()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    #endregion IDisposable Members
}

// a wrapper class to protect the object
public class WrappedImplementation : IImplementation
{
    private IImplementation objectToWrap;
    private string mySafetyString;

    public WrappedImplementation(IImplementation objectToWrap)
    {
        this.objectToWrap = objectToWrap;
        mySafetyString = "GeneratedToPreventConflicts";
    }

    #region IImplmentation Members

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        using (new SafetyWrap(mySafetyString))
        {
            objectToWrap.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public double MeasureSomething()
    {
        using (new SafetyWrap(mySafetyString))
        {
            return objectToWrap.MeasureSomething();
        }
    }

    #endregion IImplmentation Members
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IImplementation normalObject = new Implementation("dummy", 1);

        IImplementation safeObject = new WrappedImplementation(normalObject);
    }
}
```

This however involves creating a lot of boilerplate (I have in, actual fact, many interfaces to implement) and it still doesn't guarantee that they can and/or will be used everywhere that they could/should.

Is there a better alternative way to achieve this aim?

Comment: 1) What do you mean by single/multiple instance? it seems you want to ensure thread-safety.
2) this will hardly timeout :) - if (mutex.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite) == false)
                    throw new TimeoutException("Timed out trying to acquire lock");

Comment: this won't really specifically help with your problem, but is there some reason you are using a mutex instead of a regular lock?

Comment: That is because there are multiple instances of the application running.

Comment: This is just example code, a value will go in for the timeout... :)

Comment: I am interested in better ways to wrap interfaces - if there are any!

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the code.

For this, I believe a quite small generator code will do the task. You can fetch the interface members for which you want to generate wrappers and generate the code for the wrappers by a design-time T4-template. This way, you avoid duplicate concepts and can easily change all the implementation if you just alter the template from which the code was generated.

The downside of this approach is that the IntelliSense support and the default editor built into Visual Studio for T4 templates currently is very poor (actually for a long time, even).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest emitting (with `System.Reflection.Emit`) the implementation dynamically to reduce the size of dll file, amount of boilerplate in the project and compilation time.

Comment: OK, I've only been C#ing for about 6 months, so I'll google about this answer! :)

Comment: Oh, while Reflection.Emit is indeed a valid answer, you would have a hard time implementing it, particularly if you only know C# for six months. The problem is that Reflection.Emit only supports direct IL code, which is far less readable than C# code and generating it is not really funny.